# Using spacy as tokenizer in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spacy

I'm trying to use spacy as a tokenizer in a larger scikit-learn pipeline but consistently run into the problem that the task can't be pickled to be sent to the workers.

Minimal example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from functools import partial
import spacy


def spacy_tokenize(text, nlp):
    return [x.orth_ for x in nlp(text)]

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner', 'parser', 'tagger'])
tok = partial(spacy_tokenize, nlp=nlp)

pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorize', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tok)),
                     ('clf', SGDClassifier())])

params = {'vectorize__ngram_range': [(1, 2), (1, 3)]}

CV = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline,
                        param_distributions=params,
                        n_iter=2, cv=2, n_jobs=2,
                        scoring='accuracy')

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics']
news = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                          categories=categories,
                          shuffle=True,
                          random_state=42)

CV.fit(news.data, news.target)
```

Running this code I get the error:

```
PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

What confuses me is that:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(tok, open('test.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Works without a problem.

Does anybody know if it is possible to use spacy with sklearn cross-validation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a solution but a workaround. Looks like there are some issues between spacy and joblib:

- https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1669
- https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/767

If you can save the tokenizer as a function in a separate file in the directory and then import that into your current file, you can avoid this error. Something like:

- **custom_file**.py

  ```
  import spacy
  nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['ner', 'parser', 'tagger'])

  def spacy_tokenizer(doc):
      return [x.orth_ for x in nlp(doc)]
  ```
- **main**.py

  ```
  #Other code     
  ...
  ... 

  from custom_file import spacy_tokenizer

  pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorize', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=spacy_tokenizer)),
                       ('clf', SGDClassifier())])

  ...
  ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me! Although I'm confused why it works... Would be great if there would be a spacy/joblib solution at some point, as it seems to me this should be a pretty common use-case.

Comment: I didn't try the latest spacy-nightly development version though, seems like the issue might be solved there from the spacy issue you posted (https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1669)

Comment: Sorry shouldn't it be `lemma_` instead of `orth_`?

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie The above example only shows to save a spacy tokenizer. The user may use as he deems fit. `orth_` is taken from question only. If you have a different use, feel free to use `lemma_` instead.